# Symfony 2 form with two submit buttons

Tags: forms, symfony, button

So, i have a table with a checkbox on every row like this:

```
<form name="" action={{ path('mypath') }}" method="post">
 <button name="print">Print</button>
 <button name="delete">Delete</button>
 <table>
  {% for client in clienti %}
   <tr>
       <td><input type="checkbox" name="action[]" value="{{ client.id }}" /></td>
   </tr>

     .
     .
     .
  {% endfor %}
 </table>
</form>
```

Now, in my controller i want to check what button was pressed. How do i do that?

In my other forms, generated by symfony it is easy because i have a form object and
a very helpful method:

```
if ($form->get('delete')->isClicked()) {
    // delete ...
}
```

I want to know the right method to do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use e.g.

```
    $request = $this->get('request');
    if ($request->request->has('delete'))
    {
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 17):

Since Symfony 2.3 you can do:

Form:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
->add('name', 'text')
->add('save', 'submit')
->add('save_and_add', 'submit')
->getForm();
```

Controller:

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
   // ... do something

   // the save_and_add button was clicked
   if ($form->get('save_and_add')->isClicked()) {
       // probably redirect to the add page again
   }

   // redirect to the show page for the just submitted item
}
```

see here: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-3-buttons-support-in-forms

Answer (score 2):

Just create the buttons in the form builder, render them in the view and use the same method you have already used in your other forms:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('delete', 'button')
        ->add('print', 'button')
}
```

In your view:

```
<form name="" action="{{ path('mypath') }}" method="post">
    {{ form_widget(form.print) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.delete) }}

    ...
</form>
```

Comment: Your answer is good but i don't have a form builder so i needed a simpler way to do this. Thank you very much for your time.I would vote you up but i can't, i have only 14 rep. points.

Comment: I understand :) Just try to user proper forms in your applications whenever you can, it will save you headaches in the long run!

Answer (score 2):

Update for Symfony3 :

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

public function myAction(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->query->has('delete')) // For GET form
    {
        // ...
    }
    if ($request->request->get('delete')) // For POST form
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: A more universal way would be `$request->request->has('delete')` as form could be POSTing data.

Answer (score 0):

For 2023, if anybody else struggles with this, the workaround I found is the following:

Form:

```
 $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
 ->add('name', 'text')
 ->add('save', 'submit')
 ->add('save_and_add', 'submit')
 ->getForm();
```

Controller:

```
$buttonSave = $form->all()['save']
if ($buttonSave instanceof SubmitButton && $buttonSave->isClicked()) {
 //your logic here
}
```

Similar manner to `$form->all()['save_and_add']`

`$form->get('save_and_add')` returns a `FormInterface` object, not a `SubmitButton` so, you don't have access to `isClicked()` method